# Trigger to update another field in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-update

I want to run a trigger when I update a certain field on the database, so it updates another field (basically we have 2 different unique IDs for each record, so when one is changed, we need to update the other too - yay!)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name ON table AFTER
  UPDATE AS
  UPDATE table A
  SET unique_to_update = NVL(
    (SELECT b.unique_to_update_from
    FROM table b
    WHERE B.other_unique_id = A.unique_id_to_match
    ), 0);
```

I have no idea if this works (scared to test it, quite frankly, since I'm certain it'll break things) and even if it did, it'd run on every single update of that table - not just the one field that I wanted.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test anything before putting it in production.

Something like this shoud be your trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name  
BEFORE UPDATE of unique_id_to_match
ON table
FOR EACH ROW
AS
BEGIN
  select 
    NVL(
      (SELECT b.unique_to_update_from
      FROM table b
      WHERE B.other_unique_id = :new.unique_id_to_match
      ), 0)
   into :new.unique_to_update 
   FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: Many thanks, but is there anyway to run this code only when the field 'unique_id_to_match' is updated?

Comment: Just got it working with our data, unfortunately it conflicts and doesn't like updating a record that's already being updated, argh! :(

Comment: o, no, b is the same table? you are getting mutating table. we shoud find another solution. you can create a foreign key with "on update cascade" How big is your table?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, unfortunately the table has over 5,000 rows and (get this...) 900 columns. Nightmare!

Comment: Why `NVL(...)` is needed here?

Comment: @zygimantus this is the code from the question. Probably there may be nulls in the source column.

Answer (score 0):

5000 rows x  900 columns is not so big :) 
I was afraid it has 10M of rows :)

OK start

```
create temporary table tmp_my_important_columns on commit delete rows 
as 
select unique_id_to_match, unique_to_update_from, 
       other_unique_id , unique_to_update 
from table where rownum < 1;
```

second

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_before_upd_stmt
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table
AS
BEGIN
insert into 
tmp_my_important_columns 
select unique_id_to_match, unique_to_update_from, 
       other_unique_id , unique_to_update 
from table;
END;
```

third,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name  
BEFORE UPDATE of unique_id_to_match
ON table
FOR EACH ROW
AS
BEGIN
  select 
    NVL(
      (SELECT b.unique_to_update_from
      FROM tmp_my_important_columns b
      WHERE B.other_unique_id = :new.unique_id_to_match
      ), 0)
   into :new.unique_to_update 
   FROM dual;
END;
```

Comments:

- After an update, if you update the same rows again, without commit
  (which deletes the tmp table), you'll get problems. So, or you commit
  after update, or you can add an after update trigger(without for each row) that deletes all, from tmp table, but this is somehow ugly.
- You can add indexes on the temporary table.